# Postpone Synchronize Backbone.js Collection with Server

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone.js-collections, backbone-model

I have a Backbone Collection that users are performing CRUD-type activities on. I want to postpone any changes from being propagated back to the server — the `Collection.sync()` should not happen until the user initiates it (like `POSTING` a form).

As it stands, I have been able to implement on-the-fly updates with no issue (by calling things like `Model.destroy()` on the models when deleted, or `Collection.add()` to add new models to the collection. As I understand, I could pass the `{silent:true}` option to my models, preventing `.sync()` from being called during `.add()`/`.destroy()`, but from what I can tell, that could lead to some [headaches later.](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog)

I have considered overriding `Backbone.sync`, but I am not sure if that is the best route — I feel like there is some way to hook into some events, but I am not sure. Of course I have read through the Backbone docs, annotated source, and relevant SO questions before posting this, but I have hit a wall trying to extrapolate for this particular situation.

Eventually I will need to implement this in many places in my application, which is why I am concerned about best-practices at this stage. I am looking for some guidance/suggestions/thoughts on how to proceed with preventing the default behavior of immediately syncing changes with the remote server. Any help is appreciated — thank you for your time!

EDIT:

I went with Alex P's suggestion of refactoring: in my collection I set up some attributes to track the models that have been edited, added, or deleted. Then, when the user triggers the save action, I iterate through the lists and do the appropriate actions.

Comment: There is nothing wrong about `{silent: true}`, it exists because of these _rare_ situations.

Comment: @akoskm: Thanks! It looks like you're implying that this is an uncommon use case --- do you think I am looking at this functionality from a bad perspective? I feel like what I am after here isn't too crazy, but based on my investigation I keep getting the feeling that I am trying to do something that isn't recommended or suggested.

Comment: If that makes you feel better, I'm using it too. :) And I'm doing that in production, not in a Todo application. `{silent: true}` solved the same problem for me. If you're looking for a solution that works, then go with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to ensure that your collection is being synchronised when you suspect it is. `Collection.add()` shouldn't trigger a `Collection.sync()` by default (it's not mentioned in [the method documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add) or the [list of events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog), and I couldn't see a trigger in [the annotated source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html)).

`Model.destroy()` [does trigger a `sync()`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-destroy), but that shouldn't be a surprise - it's explicitly defined as "destroying a model *on the server*", and that `sync()` is performed on the model, not the collection. Your destroyed models will be removed from any collections that contain them, but I wouldn't expect those collections to `sync()` unless explicitly asked.

If your collections really are `sync()`ing when you're not expecting them to, then the most likely culprit is an event listener somewhere. Have you added any event listeners that call `sync()` for you when they see `add` or `remove` events? If your collection should `sync()` only on user interaction, can you remove those event listeners?

If not, then passing `{silent: true}` into your methods might be a viable approach. But remember that this is just stopping events from being emitted - it's not stopping that code from running. If something other than an event listener is triggering your `sync()`s, then preventing those events from being emitted won't stop them.

It would also be worth considering a wider refactor of your app. Right now you modify the collection and models immediately, and try to delay all `sync()`s until after the user clicks a button. What if you cached a list of all models to destroy & items to add, and only performed the actions when the button is clicked? Storing the model IDs would be sufficient to destroy them, and storing the collection ID and model ID would let you add items. It also means you don't have to `fetch()` the collection again if the user decides not to save their changes after all.

Comment: "What if you cached a list": This was something I was strongly considering at some point, but it felt like there might be a more efficient way to leverage Backbone. However, seeing your suggestion makes me think it is worth reconsidering --- thanks!